Spotipy app doesnt recognizes duplificated tracks
It starts, there are no errors it redirects me, I have to agree, but in the end no songs are removed can anyone help me?
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import re

def get_playlist_id(url):
    playlist_id = re.search(r'/playlist/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', url)
    if playlist_id:
        return playlist_id.group(1)
    else:
        return None

def get_duplicates(tracks):
    duplicates = {}
    for track in tracks:
        key = f"{track['track']['name']} - {track['track']['artists'][0]['name']}"
        if key in duplicates:
            duplicates[key].append(track['track']['id'])
        else:
            duplicates[key] = [track['track']['id']]
    duplicate_tracks = {key: ids for key, ids in duplicates.items() if len(ids) > 1}
    print("Duplicate tracks:", duplicate_tracks)
    return duplicate_tracks

def remove_duplicates(sp, playlist_id):
    playlist_tracks = sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id)['items']

    duplicates = get_duplicates(playlist_tracks)
    for ids in duplicates.values():
        for track_id in ids[1:]:
            sp.playlist_remove_all_occurrences_of_items(playlist_id, [track_id])

def main():
    scope = "playlist-read-collaborative playlist-modify-public"
    client_id = 'my client ID'
    client_secret = 'my client secret'
    redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3036'
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(
        auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
                                  scope=scope))
    playlist_url = 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1x76RxwKGwGq5oP3xofc3o?si=710c91480cb64fb6'
    playlist_id = get_playlist_id(playlist_url)

    if playlist_id:
        remove_duplicates(sp, playlist_id)
    else:
        print("Fehler: Playlist-ID konnte nicht aus der URL extrahiert werden.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I expect, That it removes the songs.
So after redirecting i have to agreen after that the code was executed but then no errors are spit out but the code is executed it also prints the number of duplicated songs, but the content of the {} is not present so I think that the app does not recognize the duplicated songs personally but have no idea what I can do differently can someone help me because of that?

debug your code add some print statements its hard to determine errror cause then

You don't necessary to set redirect_uri due to get playlist songs just client ID and client secret.
Spotify API paginates responses, so if your playlist has more tracks than the default page size (usually 100 tracks), you're only getting the first page of tracks. You need to handle pagination to ensure you process all tracks in the playlist.
This code can get songs and remove duplicate songs
Demo
Replace your client ID and client Secret.
import requests
import json

class MySong:
    CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'

    def __init__(self):
        self.get_token()

    def get_token(self):
        response = requests.post(url='https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                                 data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
                                 auth=(self.CLIENT_ID, self.CLIENT_SECRET))
        self.spotify_token = response.json()['access_token']

    def find_songs(self, playlist_id):
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f"Bearer {self.spotify_token}"
        }
        songs = []
        url = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}'
        while True:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            results = response.json()
            newResponse = results.get("items") or results.get("tracks", {}).get("items")
            
            if newResponse:
                for item in newResponse:
                    if item:
                        songs.append({
                            'id': item['track']['id'],
                            'name': item['track']['name'],
                            'url': item['track']['external_urls']['spotify'],
                            'album_name': item['track']['album']['name'],
                            'artists': item['track']['artists'][0]['name']
                        })
            url = results.get("next") or results.get("tracks", {}).get("next")
            if not url:  # no more songs
                break
        return songs

# Save the songs to before.json
def save_songs(songs, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(songs, f, indent=2)

# Remove duplicate songs based on their titles
def remove_duplicates(songs):
    seen_titles = set()
    unique_songs = []
    for song in songs:
        if song['name'] not in seen_titles:
            unique_songs.append(song)
            seen_titles.add(song['name'])
    return unique_songs

playlist_id = '1x76RxwKGwGq5oP3xofc3o'  # Example playlist ID
my_song = MySong()
songs = my_song.find_songs(playlist_id)

# Step 1: Save all songs to before.json
save_songs(songs, 'before.json')

# Step 2: Remove duplicates and save to after.json
unique_songs = remove_duplicates(songs)
save_songs(unique_songs, 'after.json')

# For demonstration purposes
print(json.dumps(songs[:3], indent=2))  # print first 3 songs
print(json.dumps(songs[-3:], indent=2))  # print last 3 songs
print("Before remove duplicated songs: ", len(songs))  # print total number of songs
print("After remove duplicated songs: ", len(unique_songs))  # print number of unique songs

Result
Will saved two json files.
Before.json: Before remove duplicated songs
After.json: After remove duplicated songs


